# Android Limit ball withing screen

Tags: android

I want to limit the ball not to go out of the screen, I have the check :

```
if(myBall.x - myBall.radius> 0 && myBall.x+myBall.radius < mainLayout.getWidth()) {
  myBall.invalidate();
}
```

The movement happens with the accelerometer on highest sensivity ( the ball moves fast ) and the problem that happens is that the ball sometimes goes half off the screen. How can I prevent that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ball moves by a certain pixels each time so it is definitely going to go out of the screen often, you will need to create a method that returns the ball back in the screen if it goes out and sets it bounds there then draw it and execure the `invalidate()` method

if the ball is moving horizontally then you will just set x to 0 if it goes out from the left side and set it to window.width() if it goes out from the right.

**EDIT:**

not sure what you mean by jumpy, but i'd guess you are drawing the ball when it goes out then take it back inside then draw again, if so then you need to correct it to draw after you validate that it is not outside.

and your code is a bit messy, try to neat it up, something like:

```
if(ball.x > 0 && (ball.x + ball.width) < window.width())    //check what matters only
 { return_ball_inside;  //correct mistakes
   repaint();
 }
invalidate();  //just call it after the corrections rather than in every condition
```

Comment: Hi, I wrote this : http://jsfiddle.net/6u13getv/ ( see html code ), but the ball seems jumpy :( thanks though for the answer